# How to get QuerySet of ForeignKey field Django

Tags: django

I have two models. First one:

```
class KvantMessage(models.Model):
    text        = models.TextField(blank=True)
    style_text  = models.TextField(blank=True)
    receivers   = models.ManyToManyField(MailReceiver)
    date        = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    files       = models.ManyToManyField(FileStorage, blank=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Письмо')
    sender      = models.ForeignKey(KvantUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
```

And second one:

```
class ImportantMail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(KvantUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mail = models.ForeignKey(KvantMessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The question is, how to get all mails instances as "KvantMails" from "ImportantMail" where user is equal to some *user*.

P.S. Hope you understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
KvantMessage.objects.filter(importantmail__user=some_user)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

Comment: It's not, what I'm looking for. I want to get all KvantMails instance from filed "mails"

Comment: @user18075594: the answer has been edited based on, what I think, is the question after the clarification. Now it filters `KvantMessage`s (I assume you meant `KvantMessage` instead of `KvantMail`)?

Comment: Yep, now it seems to work. Thanks you a lot